# Do something with data from timer

Tags: javascript, if-statement, setinterval

i have a question. 
What i'm trying to do is:
I have an interval function running. Every 5 seconds energy is going down by 1. 
I want to do something once when var energy is 66 or less. (Also when energy is smaller than 50 but thats for later). But it won't show the if state, only the else. Can someone help me please?

```
var energy = 70;

setInterval    (function () {
    energy = energy - 1;
    $("#energiegetal").val(energy);
    }, 5000);

if (energy < 67){
    console.log("works")    
}

else    {
    console.log("not working")
}
```

Comment: You're checking energy right after setting up the interval, before it has time to go down. You have to check the energy after you decrement it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `function` needs to include your `if` statement, like this:

```
var energy = 70;
setInterval (function () {
    energy = energy - 1;
    $("#energiegetal").val(energy);

    if (energy < 67){
        console.log("works")    
    }
    else {
        console.log("not working")
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @sherb is probably all you need.  But if your code is more complex, you might want to break this into distinct parts that don't know about each other.  One way of doing that is by connecting the parts through some sort of signalling system, such as an anonymous PubSub/EventEmitter mechanism.  There are lots of them out there.  With a global `events` module, this might turn the code into something like this:

```
(function() {
    var energy = 70; // local to this IIFE

    setInterval(function() {
        energy = energy -1;
        events.emit('energyChanged', energy);
    }, 5000);
}());

events.on('energyChanged', function(energy) {
    if (energy < 67){
        console.log("works")    
    } else {
        console.log("not working")
    }
});
```

As I said, this is probably overkill for your case, but it's a good thing to have available when your requirements demand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one beginner-friendly way to do this:

```
var energy = 70;
var period = 5000; //ms

var test67 = function() {
    energy = energy - 1;
    $("#energiegetal").val(energy);
    if (energy < 67) {
        console.log("67 works");
        setTimeout(test50, period);
    } else {
        setTimeout(test67, period);
    }
};

var test50 = function() {
    energy = energy - 1;
    $("#energiegetal").val(energy);
    if (energy < 50) {
        console.log("50 works");
        setTimeout(keepDropping, period);
    } else {
        setTimeout(test50, period);
    }
};

var keepDropping = function() {
    energy = energy - 1;
    $("#energiegetal").val(energy);
    setTimeout(keepDropping, period);
};

setTimeout(test67, period);
```

You can see it in action on **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mavoho/1/edit?js,console,output)**.  There's plenty not to like about this, primarily having to do with repetition, but it should be fairly understandable.

I couldn't tell if you wanted the energy to continue dropping after your second threshhold.  If not, you can remove that function and the `setTimeout` call that makes reference to it.

Note the difference between `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.  With `setTimeout`, we manually trigger each next call.  With `setInterval`, they happen continually, but it's more difficult to know when to cancel or change the functions used.

An alternative to this would be to use flags for each of your threshholds, reporting whether they'd been run, and checking the flags each time to see whether that threshhold had already been tripped.

There are many other alternatives, almost all with shorter code than this.  But this is about as explicit as I can imagine.